# How to avoid saving a file on hard drive?

Tags: java, file, file-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Each time I run the following code, the file is saved on a hard drive. However, I want it to be saved only in the Object Storage container.

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder()
                .endpoint("...")
                .credentials("...","...")
                .tenantName("...")
                .authenticate();

        String containerName = "MyImgs";
        String objectName = "test.jpg";

BufferedWriter output = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(objectName);
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            output.write(text);
            String etag = os.objectStorage().objects().put(containerName, 
                                                           objectName, 
                                                           Payloads.create(f));
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
I am using this [API](http://openstack4j.com).

Comment: Which library are you using? The answer will depend on what the API supports.

Comment: Remove the 3 code lines(which btw is buggy since it doesn't close the streams) that writes it to a file ? Is there something we're missing here ?

Comment: It depends on API / envinronment You use. generally Java has plenty of in-RAM writters / readers

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I am using import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File; import java.io.FileWriter;

Comment: @Jacek Cz: Please see my update. I am working in Eclipse.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos This is not the library you are having trouble with.  These are built in classes in any case.  `text` is already in memory so you wouldn't need to write to a file if you didn't want to.  The library I assume you are asking about is the `OSClient` and `Payloads`.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Ok, sorry. I am using this API: http://www.openstack4j.com/

Comment: @KlausosKlausos so by looking at the Javadoc for the class you are using you get the answer below. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Javadoc for [Payloads](http://www.openstack4j.com/javadoc/org/openstack4j/model/common/Payloads.html) it has a method which takes in InputStream. To read an String as an InputStream you can do

```
Payloads.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
```

This will avoid the need to create a file just so you have something to read.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the OpenStack4j API it is possible to create a payload from an `InputStream`, so why don't you do that instead of from a `File`?

Convert the `text` to an `InputStream` with a helper function like this:

```
private static InputStream newInputStreamFrom(String text) {
    try {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(); // should not occur
    }
}
```

And then your code could look something like this:

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder()
            .endpoint("...")
            .credentials("...","...")
            .tenantName("...")
            .authenticate();

    String containerName = "MyImgs";
    String objectName = "test.jpg";
    InputStream stream = newInputStreamFrom(text);
    String etag = os.objectStorage().objects().put(containerName, 
                                                       objectName,
                                                       Payloads.create(stream));
```